# How to select from the db where version field is the recent one

Tags: php, mysql, select, max

I have a table called 'pricing' which has so many fields including 'distributor' and 'version'. Distributor field is the id  from the distributor table. Each distributor has different versions. Versions like: **20131109AV-V1,20131110AV-V2,20131112AV-V3** are the versions for distributor=1 AND **20131111WC-V1,20131111WC-V2** are the versions for distributor=2 etc. I need to select all the data from pricing table where version equals the recent version of each distributor.

Eg: 20131112AV-V3 is the latest version of distributor=1
    20131111WC-V2 is the latest version of distributor=2

Can I make the query in one step?

Or do I need to query part by part like, select distributor and version first, then loop through the table using distributor and latest version(code is given below:)?

```
$all_distributors=mysql_query("SELECT `distributor`,MAX(`version`) as `version` FROM `pricing` GROUP BY `distributor`",$con);
while($all_dist= mysql_fetch_array($all_distributors))
{
    $latest_version=$all_dist['version'];
    $distributor=$all_dist['distributor'];
    echo $distributor."-".$latest_version."<br/>";
        //Again select the query using this $distributor & $latest_version

}
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a single query for this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM pricing p
    JOIN 
        (
            SELECT distributor, MAX(version) AS ver 
            FROM pricing 
            GROUP BY distributor
        ) mx ON mx.ver = p.version AND p.distributor = mx.distributor
```